# How can Githzerai and Githyanki both be Chaotic Aligned and Psionicists?

Tags: psionics, alignment, adnd-1e, gith

How can Githzerai and Githyanki both be Chaotic Aligned and Psionicists?

Furthermore, there's a handful of Psionic races with powers, typically equal to their level, with no apparent restriction, but these creatures are chaotic.

Comment: Please review the help article on [how to ask a good question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). There appears to be several questions here, with little to no context. Voting to close.

Comment: As a suggestion on how to improve this question, you might add why you think being Chaotic would prevent them from being Psionicists.  Is there a rule in AD&D that made that restriction?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: AD&D 2E (at least) did in fact forbid Chaotic alignment for psionicists. You could have a wild talent regardless of alignment, but the self-discipline necessary to develop psionic abilities was considered impossible to achieve with a chaotic alignment.

Comment: While it might be nice to include the context in the question, ultimately, *the point of asking questions is to get expert advice*. Anyone qualified to answer this question would know the context, and would be able to answer this as-is. Therefore, it’s a fine question, and should be open.

Comment: The entire speculative section of the question is several questions and speculative. That was why I voted to close.

Comment: @NautArch same here. If it was one question that looked objectively answerable I wouldn't vtc. But it is not. It is hard to know what specific problem OP has here.

Comment: They are all deeply related questions, so combining them into one question is entirely appropriate. They are all on-topic questions that can be answered well and backed up. The OP might use the *word* “speculative,” but they aren’t, really, and shouldn’t be answered that way. If you object to a single word, editing is far more appropriate than closing.

Comment: @kryan, in that case it's merely a wording issue. If you can, please do [edit] it down to **one core question** that you feel you can answer, and if it is possible as you said, keep the surrounding context so you can cover everything the original question covers.

Comment: I've made an update to refocus your question on the primary title question. I think answers may likely cover your thoughts, but if you disagree please rollback or update my edit.

Comment: Since when is the term 'psionicist' applied to anything in AD&D 1e?  I think you are cross referencing editions here. Psionics is an optional rule in the PHB (and thus an optional rule throughout; E.G.G. apparently was not happy with the can of worms he'd opened) and I note that in the MM and MM2 that term does not come up in a word search.  Will check the fiend folio later, but I suggest that you rethink your assumptions on this question.  (A better question might be how can a githzeri be a monk, with the lawful requirement ... but I don't worry about that kind of hair splitting in AD&D 1e)

Comment: Beyond that, if you go to the source material for Psionics in AD&D 1e, which is the PHB, on pages 109 for the basics, there is no alignment restriction/requirement.  Your question is thus based on an invalid premise.  If this gets re opened I'll point that out in an answer. AD&D 2e had psionicist.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to re tag this to AD&D 2e? The restriction you mention is explicitly spelled out in the Complete Psionicist's Handbook; it is nowhere in AD&D 1e.